# Make div appear when enter is pressed

Tags: javascript, html, button, keyboard

I have a input where a user can input text and when the user presses enter on their keyboard, it will click the button 'Go!' which should then make the 'Create Div' button appear. And a div is created with the user's inputted text, when they click the 'Create Div' button. But I want this button to be clicked also when the user presses enter. Thus when the user presses 'Enter' the first time, it will click the 'Go!' button which will make the 'Create Div' button appear and then when the user presses 'Enter' the second time ( or preferably when the 'Create Div' button is shown on the screen) then the actual div will be created with the user's inputted text.
I tried doing this in Javascript, by using an IF statement but right now when I press 'Enter' the first time to trigger the 'Go!' button, it automatically triggers the 'Create Div' button and the div appears right after the first 'Enter' is pressed (uncomment the last bit of my JS code to see what I mean) What should I change to get my desired result?

```js
var button = document.getElementById("button");
var createbutton = document.createElement("button");
var creatediv = document.createElement("div");

button.addEventListener('click', function(){
createbutton.innerHTML = "Create Div";
createbutton.style.display = 'inline-block';
document.getElementById("body").appendChild(createbutton);
});

createbutton.addEventListener('click', function(){
createbutton.style.display = 'none';
var input = document.getElementById("input").value;
creatediv.innerHTML = input;
document.getElementById("body").appendChild(creatediv);
});

document.onkeydown = function(event){
if(event.keyCode == 13){
button.click();
}
}

/*if(createbutton.style.display = 'inline-block'){
document.onkeydown = function(event){
if(event.keyCode == 13){
createbutton.click();
}
}
}*/
```

```html
<body id="body">
<input type="text" id="input" placeholder="Text goes here">
<button id="button">Go!</button>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can give your `createbutton`and ID and check if the element is inside the DOM
when enter is pressed:

```js
var button = document.getElementById("button");
var createbutton = document.createElement("button");
var creatediv = document.createElement("div");

button.addEventListener('click', function(){
    createbutton.innerHTML = "Create Div";
    createbutton.style.display = 'inline-block';
    createbutton.id = 'createButton';
    document.getElementById("body").appendChild(createbutton);
});

createbutton.addEventListener('click', function(){
    createbutton.style.display = 'none';
    var input = document.getElementById("input").value;
    creatediv.innerHTML = input;
    document.getElementById("body").appendChild(creatediv);
});

document.onkeydown = function(event){
    if(event.keyCode === 13) {
        if(document.getElementById('createButton')) {
            createbutton.click();
        } else {
            button.click();
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<body id="body">
<input type="text" id="input" placeholder="Text goes here">
<button id="button">Go!</button>
</body>
```

Comment: Very pleasant answer.